# Open ID Connect Session Management Access/Refresh Token vs Session iFrame

Tags: session, oauth-2.0, openid, openid-connect

We have a web app in which we allow users to log into the app using any Open ID provider(e.g. Okta, Google, Facebook etc.). We want to implement the correct Open ID Connect prescribed methodology/workflow to keep the user logged into the site.

The existing implementation, looks at the expiry of the Access Token then if it's close to expiry uses a Refresh Token to get a new Access Token to keep the user logged in. I feel like this is wrong. When a user logs in to the web app, the Identity Token is used to Authenticate the identity of the user using the Authorization Code workflow. The Access Token and Refresh Token are stored on the server side. Periodically, the Refresh Token is used to get new Access Tokens to keep the user logged into the site. I believe this is a security risk because -

Imagine if a user is logged onto his OP account in a browser. He opens up Sky and is directly logged into MP because he’s already logged into MP. He then in a separate tab, logs out of his OP account. He will continue to be logged into MP for days on the basis of this Refresh Token/Access Token mechanism! Isn’t this a security risk?

If feel like the correct way to go about this is to use Session Management using iframes as prescribed here on OIDC - 
https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-session-1_0.html

For more context, when a user logs into our WebApp we pull data from the OP's UserInfo endpoint to create a profile within our WebApp and set permissions/roles within our app based on data sent over from the OP's UserInfo endpoint. We continue doing this periodically. For this purpose, I feel like using the Access Token(and using the Refresh Token to get new Access Token) to access the UserInfo API is correct because it conforms to the OAuth 2.0 concept of protecting/authorizing API/Resource endpoints using Access Tokens.

I want to know if this is indeed the correct way to manage how a user should be logged in when supporting Open ID Connect.

Comment: Sandunes90, have you checked my answer? Did it help or did you solve the problem in some other way?

Answer (score 1):

I think the first question is whether you want to bind the lifetime of an OpenID Connect provider Single Sign On session with the session of your application. You just want to authenticate a user using their OpenID Connect service. If I logout of Google, I expect to be logged out of GMail, but not a third-party application that used Google for authentication. Would you like to implement Single Sign Out as well?

But if I wanted to be logged out when you logout of the OpenID Connect provider, I would implement the [OpenID Connect Session management](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-session-1_0.html). There is one thing good to be aware of when using `iframes` and cookies - browsers have an option to "Block third-party cookies" (that's how Chrome calls it), it's turned off by default, but as far as I know, it disables the SSO functionality when turned on.

I'm not sure why you request the userinfo endpoint periodically. If you just want to check whether the access token is still valid, you could also use the [token introspection endpoint](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7662).

For security concerns, I would suggest you to read the [OAuth 2.0 for Browser-Based Apps RFC](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-browser-based-apps-00). It recommends using the auth code flow with [PKCE](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7636) instead of the implicit flow. With the implicit flow, access tokens transported in redirect URLs stay in network and browser caches and can be used right away by an attacker. The auth code with PKCE needs a `code_verifier` (one-time secret) in order to be exchanged for tokens. So I would first check how the providers work with a configuration you choose and if it's even supported.